# Access application database from another application of my own

Tags: android

I have 2 application. The first (Application **A**) is the primary app, the second (Application **B**) is a helping application and depends on **A** to get and process the data.

How can I make a secure, reliable and efficient communication between the two application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ContentProvider` to get your work done here.

`ContentProvider` is for sharing data between your application and make authority to unique and you can store data in encrypted form to secure your data.

Comment: I believe that the data stored using the `ContentProvider` is accessible from all applications, isn't it? I think encrypting the data is not a good idea especially if you intent to share large data.

Comment: @Dazents Yes If they know content Provider content URI, but other than this you can not do this in better way

Comment: I see. What about using broadcasts to query application **A** and return the data? Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: @Dazents IMO You can't.

Answer (score 1):

A content provider manages access to a central repository of data. You implement a provider as one or more classes in an Android application, along with elements in the manifest file. One of your classes implements a subclass ContentProvider, which is the interface between your provider and other applications. Although content providers are meant to make data available to other applications, you may of course have activities in your application that allow the user to query and modify the data managed by your provider.

[click this to know how to create Content Provider](https://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/)

Comment: As you've mentioned the `ContentProvider` is accessible by other applications. Which mean all unauthorized applications will have access to the data. How can I make queries to the application, but without using activities? (I want a way to work in the background. So, is that possible to achieve using broadcasts?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Provider.here is a demo example for reference https://github.com/lalit3686/CustomContentProviderDemo